# How do I determine which repository is slowing me down?

Tags: 11.10, updates, repository

Whenever I check for updates with the update manager or Synaptic (I don't like the Software Center so I don't use it), there seems to be one repository that takes forever to check. The progress bar stops at something like 230 out of 231 files, and then hangs there for minutes on end.

If I click on "Show for individual files" there's this huge list of files, and a lot of them seem to repeat, and they aren't ordered by progress, so it's near impossible to search through them.

Is there a way I can figure out which repository, file, or whatever it is that is causing the slowdown so I can determine what to do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `sudo apt-get update` in a terminal and watch the progress. The last line where the update stalls will be the one that slows down the process.

(If you have Chrome installed from Google then `dl.google.com` seems to have difficulties at the moment. [Check status.](http://www.isup.me/dl.google.com))